# Put image over two another

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm placing 7 images on the screen which has all the same width. I'm using it by setting weight. But now I need to place few images on them, more precisely betweem image 1/2 2/3 etc. To create something like this:
[image]
What is the best way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go.

You need to use android:clipChildren on the parent layout and align each overlapping imageview to the top left of the child relativelayout with a negative margin of width/2 so that they won't get drawn over by the next relativelayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipChildren="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, but what if there are 7 elements in background and black one should be between 1/2 2/3 4/5 5/6 6/7?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by aligning the overlaying imageviews to the top right of a relativelayout and using a combination of negative margins and settings android:clipChildren to false

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution to your comment.  You actually need to align to the top left rather than the top right, else the next relativelayout will draw on top of the overlapping imageview